# Blank unmet depenicies box

Tags: games, 21.04, arm64

i am running the most recent version of Ubuntu on a RPi 4 with 4 gb of ram. when i try to install GZDoom using the official Ubuntu build it comes up with the pop-up saying "Unable to install GZDoom: The following packages have unmet dependencies:" i have allready tried installing -f, and that did not fix the problem. edit: i am using vershion 21.04

Comment: Your actual release number or name would be helpful. Lots of people are mistaken about "*the most recent version*". Showing us your actual input and output is critical. Summaries lack vital details.

Comment: @user535733  i am using 21.04, if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "install GZDoom using the official Ubuntu build"? Which source do you use? Which CPU arch do you use on RPi - armhf or arm64?

Comment: @N0rbert 1: the Ubuntu build on this site: https://zdoom.org/downloads 2: idk 3: arm64

Comment: If you are downloading [gzdoom_4.6.1_amd64.deb](https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom/releases/download/g4.6.1/gzdoom_4.6.1_amd64.deb) then you should know that amd64 deb can't be installed on arm64.

Comment: @N0rbert ok guess I’m dumb.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the way to install on ARM64 seems to be [compilation](https://zdoom.org/wiki/Compile_GZDoom_on_Linux) on RPi.